# Averaging slopes from multiple linear regressions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, interaction

So I am interested in a potential study that involves measuring a change in two variables (one independent and one dependent) over time. For a single participant and a given time interval, one can measure the change in each variable. This gives a data point on the plot of change in dependent variable vs change in the independent variable. Repeating this for each time interval gives a collection of data points that one can perform a linear regression on. Thus, for each participant, we get a scatter plot and a line of best fit.

The study separates the participants into two groups. The group determines the way in which the dependent variable is modulated. I expect that for one of the groups, the lines of best fit will on average have larger slopes. How can I compare the slopes between the two different groups? I considered averaging the slopes for each group and directly comparing the averages but this seems quite naive. Is there a general way of comparing the slopes of the two groups (perhaps by obtaining two distributions of slopes)? Or would it be more accurate to analyse the data in a completely different way?

Comment: Welcome to CV! A difference in slopes is usually modelled as an interaction, is this what you mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)

Comment: One analysis to consider is using the median value, that is, 1/2 above and 1/2 below, rather than average. If the distribution of slope values is Gaussian normal, then the median and mean values are the same, but if they are not then this might be helpful.